# Gradle Custom Plugin: How To Configure A Gradle Task Using Properties Expected to be Set in the Build Script

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to write a custom Gradle plugin and I need to configure a 'Zip' task on my project using properties the values of which I'm expecting to be provided by the build script (build.gradle).

Here's the relevant section of my build.gradle script:

```
oozie {
  sourceSets {
    workflow {
      dslDir = 'workflow/dsl'
      dslCopySpec = {
        rename { it - ~/\.[^\.]+$/ + '.xml' }
        filter(OozieDslFilter)
      }
      resourceDir = 'workflow/resources'
      resourceCopySpec = {}
    }
    coordinator {
      dslDir = 'coordinator/dsl'
      dslCopySpec = {
        rename { it - ~/\.[^\.]+$/ + '.xml' }
        filter(OozieDslFilter)
      }
      resourceDir = 'coordinator/resources'
      resourceCopySpec = {}
    }
  }
}
```

And here's my plugin code that currently doesn't do what I expect:

```
class Oozie implements Plugin<Project> {

  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.configurations {
      oozieLibs {
        description = /Java libraries (jars) to be downloaded and included in the workflow 'lib' directory/
        transitive = true
      }
    }

    project.extensions.create('oozie',
        OozieExtension,
        project.container(OozieSourceSet)
    )

    project.task('build', type: Zip) {
      group = 'Oozie Workflow Build'
      with {
        archiveName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.${extension}"
        destinationDir = project.buildDir
      }
      from(project.configurations.oozieLibs) {
        into 'lib'
      }

      // project.oozie.sourceSets is empty at this time for obvious reasons.
      println project.oozie.sourceSets

      project.oozie.sourceSets.each { OozieSourceSet sourceSet ->
        println sourceSet
        from(sourceSet.dslDir, sourceSet.dslCopySpec)
        from(sourceSet.resourceDir, sourceSet.resourceCopySpec)
      }
    }

    project.task('clean', type: Delete) {
      group = 'Oozie Workflow Build'
      delete project.buildDir
    }
  }

}
```

I'm expecting to be able to read the values of properties like project.oozie.sourceSets inside my plugin's 'apply' method.

However, at the time when my custom plugin's 'apply' method is called, the value for project.oozie.sourceSets is empty because the build.gradle script which sets the value for that property hasn't been executed yet.

How do I approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could describe more explicitly what's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks @EricWendelin I've updated the question with some explanation. Please let me know if you think more info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with is:

```
class Oozie implements Plugin<Project> {

  static final String DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION_FINDER_REGEX = /\.[^\.]+$/
  static final String DEFAULT_EXTENSION_REPLACEMENT = '.xml'
  final static DEFAULT_WORKFLOW_ROOT = 'workflow'
  final static DEFAULT_COORDINATOR_ROOT = 'coordinator'
  final static DEFAULT_DSL_DIR = 'dsl'
  final static DEFAULT_RESOURCE_DIR = 'resources'

  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.configurations {
      oozieLibs {
        description = /Java libraries (jars) to be downloaded and included in the workflow 'lib' directory/
        transitive = true
      }
    }

    project.extensions.create('oozie',
        OozieExtension,
        project.container(OozieSourceSet)
    )

    project.oozie.sourceSets {
      workflow {
        dslCopySpec = {
          from("${DEFAULT_WORKFLOW_ROOT}/${DEFAULT_DSL_DIR}") {
            rename { it - ~DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION_FINDER_REGEX + DEFAULT_EXTENSION_REPLACEMENT }
            filter(OozieWorkflowDslFilter)
          }
        }
        resourceCopySpec = {
          from("${DEFAULT_WORKFLOW_ROOT}/${DEFAULT_RESOURCE_DIR}")
        }
      }
      coordinator {
        dslCopySpec = {
          from("${DEFAULT_COORDINATOR_ROOT}/${DEFAULT_DSL_DIR}") {
            rename { it - ~DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION_FINDER_REGEX + DEFAULT_EXTENSION_REPLACEMENT }
            filter(OozieWorkflowDslFilter)
          }
        }
        resourceCopySpec = {
          from("${DEFAULT_COORDINATOR_ROOT}/${DEFAULT_RESOURCE_DIR}")
        }
      }
    }

    project.task('build', type: Zip) {
      group = 'Oozie Workflow Build'
      with {
        archiveName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.${extension}"
        destinationDir = project.buildDir
      }
    }

    project.task('clean', type: Delete) {
      group = 'Oozie Workflow Build'
      delete project.buildDir
    }

    project.afterEvaluate {
      project.build.with {
        from(project.configurations.oozieLibs) {
          into 'lib'
        }
      }

      project.oozie.sourceSets.each { OozieSourceSet sourceSet ->
        project.build.with(sourceSet.dslCopySpec)
        project.build.with(sourceSet.resourceCopySpec)
      }
    }
  }

}
```